# How do I apply font-awesome alongside text in Jade without messing up my CSS?

Tags: pug, font-awesome

My understanding is that when using Jade, font-awesome icons need to be inside of an a tag. But when I do this, the text that I want to associate with the hyperlink loses the formatting from my CSS. An example of what I am talking about is shown in the example picture below. I am also including the Jade code that I'm using. In the photo, you can see that the "All Ships" text is not formatted consistently after the font-awesome icon was inserted Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
nav#mainNav Main Menu
        .menu
            a(href="/")
                i.fa.fa-ship(aria-hidden='true')  All Ships
            br
            br
            a(href='/addreview') Add Review
            br
            br
            a(href='/topships') Top Rated Ships
            br
            br
            a(href='/bestdining') Best Dining
            br
            br
            a(href='/worstships') Lowest Rated Ships
            br
            br
            a(href='/recentreviews') Most Recent Reviews
            br
            br
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Pug code is compiling the text "All Ships" inside of an `<i>` element with font-awesome classes, which is likely overriding your previously set text styles.

---

Your code:

```
a(href="/")
  i.fa.fa-ship(aria-hidden='true')  All Ships
```

Compiles to:

```html
<a href="/"><i class="fa fa-ship" aria-hidden="true"> All Ships</i></a>
```

---

Revising your code to the below will place the "All Ships" text as a sibling to the icon, as desired.

```
a(href="/")
  i.fa.fa-ship(aria-hidden='true')
  | All Ships
```

Compiles to:

```html
<a href="/"><i class="fa fa-ship" aria-hidden=""></i> All Ships</a>
```